# How can I specify the number of a instances of a given field in a View

Tags: drupal, drupal-views, drupal-7

I have standard basic article content type which, amongst other things, contains an image field which is configured to contain an unlimited amount of values.

I'm now trying to create a view that lists some of the fields in this content type but I want to limit the number of images that are returned for this specific field to 3 random images in the list (or less).  Is this something that can be achieved right in my view configuration or do I need to do something ninja?  I'm not aware of everything that's possible php wise to "rewrite" / "filter" the results of my view but I'm confortable with anything programming related.

I'm using drupal-7 with Views 7.x-3.0-alpha1

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

AFAIK there is no way through the Views UI to randomize the selections of a grouped field.

I can see two possible ways, *in theory* to achieve what you want.

1. Use `hook_views_query_alter` to alter the SQL query for the view. I'm not sure Views support what you need to randomize the results, but you have the ability to alter the query that views generates, and might be able to randomize it.
2. Select all results, but using theming to only show the randomly selected options. This could be done in a preprocess function. Views provides several, depending on your display option, `hook_views_view_unformatted` might be what you need.